# centerHorizontal not working in relative layout, screen rotation is landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

**why android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" in top relative layout is not working but in child where it is in code, is working?**

My outer layout is relative and other code is below.
Does screen orientation is a factor?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/twenty" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wait_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/text_waitingforplayers" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/text_baught"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/wait_text"
        android:background="@drawable/text_youhavebought" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/used_bingo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/wait_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_baught"
        android:text="1333" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bingo_cards"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/wait_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/used_bingo"
        android:background="@drawable/text_bingocards" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ballas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bingo_cards"
        android:background="@drawable/balls" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_claim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ballas"
        android:background="@drawable/text_logintoclaim" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about hierarchy. When you set **android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"** on any view it means you are setting that view to center in the horizontal space acquired by its parent. if you want that you set **android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"** on parent view and all its child will be centered so you will have to make its **height** and **width** **wrap_content**. But for doing this you have to make an another parent view of that relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` for the inside relative layout also.

And also screen orientation is not a factor if we have designed correctly.

Comment: I have already done that.My question is why it is not working only in relative layout why do i need to put in each child.

Comment: Ya, bcs if you put inside relative layout it will only align that layout to the center of its parent and not its child element in center..